# How to implement Unique Custom Metric in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Consider a web application that gives out services to different schools, that is, each log in credentials consist of three parts: school code, username and password. I've been asked to setup Google Analytics for this website and create a couple of reports for it.

There's one particular report which I still couldn't figure out how to implement: The number of active schools per date. An active school is one which some student of it has used the website. Here's my approach so far:

I decided to incorporate `event`s and send them regardless of page load (it's a Single Page Application anyway). I would then send an event for each log in including the school code. To keep the question short, no matter what I did I could not find a way to count the correct number of active schools. I've tested with `Unique Events`, `Custom Dimensions` and `Custom Metrics`. In case of `Unique Events`, sessions disturb the results  and in case of `Custom Metrics`, there's no such thing as "Unique Custom Metric"!

The worst part is that each new solution I would want to test takes me a day! And it's driving me crazy (patience is not my specialty).

**[UPDATE]**

To make the question easier to understand, consider having a web-shop that sells different kinds of products. How can you create a report in GA that shows **how many unique products' pages have been seen** for a period of time? i. e., if product X's page has been seen today, it will increment today's bar by one in the report, regardless of how many times it's been seen.

Comment: Why do sessions disturb the results?

Comment: It's pretty straight forward! Just try to count the number of active schools and you'll get it.

Comment: Question #1: What kind of website?

Comment: @LoydChristmas Does it really matter? Mine is an SPA but even an ordinary webshop would face the same problem if you want to count the number of visited products in an interval (like mentioned in the update).

Comment: Well was going to suggest some cool CMS based solutions if you were on a CMS (drupal, WP).. but whatevs.

Answer (score 6):

your task in a first look is pretty simple, but it fact - it's not.
What you can try to do: each time, when user logged in, send event with parameters:

- Category: unique school identifier
- Action: whatever you want (for
  example, hashed login or user ID)
- Label: empty.

After simulation data looks like:[image]
As event labels are unique for each school, then count of active schools per day - is count of rows at table with events(marked at image).

What's bad in this approach:

1. You can only choose one separate day to analyse, how many schools were active. So you can't choose range like May 1 - May 5 and get report with count of active schools per day. You should manually choose five 1-day periods(May 1- May 1, May 2 - May 2 and so on) and manually grab count of rows in events table for each day.
2. Unfortunately, you can't access to metric "Count of rows" in Google Analytics interface and show it at custom report. This may available at Google Analytics API(require a lot of programming, not sure that it's what do you need).

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an acceptable solution! I need to create a report for my customer and he won't take `row count` as a solution. Plus being able to aggregate over different period of times (days, weeks, months) is a requirement of mine. Thank you for your time anyway.

Comment: In that case is possible use Google Analytics API for reporting, or create some solution at server-side, which will send event for each school after login only once per day.

Comment: Requests should be sent to GA through client (browser), so no server side solution is acceptable. But if you think GA API can help, why not!?

Comment: For GA API you need resources for programming, that's take some time. But you can try, if you have programming experience, this may allow you to create desired report for client.

Answer (score 2):

In the standard data layout this cannot be precalculated as you are in essence counting the number of unique dimensions on the date.

But there are two exceptional dimensions that require joining data to build their normal views: `userId` and `transactionId`.

So you could either give everyone in one group the same user id or a shared transaction.

As an example, if you create a transaction with an id of Date+schoolId whenever a use logs in, there will be as many transactions on any day as there are active schools on that day.

Answer (score 0):

You need some tiny persistence on the server side.

Let the web page include an `iframe` pointing to a file whose name is the date + school name (or other granularity as you may need). Let the 404 handler *create* (not return) a blank HTML file with the requested name that *doesn't* call GA, but returns HTTP code 200 and HTML that includes the GA calls. This way the GA-API will be called only once per school per date, so you'll get the GA report you're looking for.

Points to note:

- Better to keep the files in a separate directory with their own `.htaccess` (or your web server's specific equivalent) and 404 handler, to avoid conflicts with the site's code.
- You should probably clean those files once in a while.
- The client's javascript `Date` object might be wrong, it is better to get the current time from the `Date:` header of a reliable server (e.g. Google's).
- It is also possible to implement this mechanism with all scripting done client side, though it makes things a bit more complicated. Let me know if you have absolutely no way of adding scripts on the server side.